# Naturality/when diagrams commute in Commutative Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, tensors

As I work my way through commutative algebra (Atiyah and Macdonald), I am often confronted with the following sort of scenario.  One has an exact sequence
$$
0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0
$$
of modules over a commutative ring $R$, one applies some functor (like tensoring with a flat $R$-module $N$) to the sequence, uses some canonical isomorphisms concerning tensor products in a commutative diagram, and obtains a new exact sequence which is somehow easier to evaluate to show what you want.  One example of what I mean is the following problem (exercise 3.17):

Let $A \overset{f}\to B \overset{g}\to C$ be ring homomorphisms.  If $g \circ f$ is flat and $g$ is faithfully flat, then $f$ is flat.

One approach to this problem is to consider an injection $N \to M$ of $A$-modules,  let $P$ be the kernel of $N \otimes_A B \to M \otimes_A C$, and note that we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \to P \otimes_B C \to N \otimes_A B \otimes_B C \to M \otimes_A B \otimes_B C.
$$
We have canonical isomorphisms $N \otimes_A B \otimes_B C \cong N \otimes_A C$ and $M \otimes_A B \otimes_B C \cong M \otimes_A C$, and can check that the diagram
[image]

commutes.  One can then use the bottom row of the diagram to say that by flatness of $C$ over $A$ we must have $P \otimes_B C = 0$, and by faithful flatness of $C$ over $B$, we must then have $P = 0$, so that $B$ is flat over $A$.

This strategy of checking some diagram involving canonical isomorphisms commutes seems to be coming up again and again, and each time I just run through the arrows and check that the diagram does indeed commute.  I am wondering, however, if there is some good "higher level" reason why these diagrams commute in general, and also I wonder if in practice people generally just check each new diagram they have commutes or if there is some more general phenomenon at play here that allows you to say all diagrams arising in a certain way must commute.  I have heard of naturality in algebraic topology, and this sort of thing seems to be quite related.  Thanks!

Comment: If something is nice enough, then it is usually a natural transformation - and this is exactly the naturality comes up. So the general phenomenon you are looking for is to study category theory in which one studies such notions. Sometimes, if it is an ad hoc naturality, then one does have to check it by hand (but usually it will be clear that it works because of how canonical the map is and no choices are involved).

Comment: Indeed, this is related to algebraic topology, said naturality in topology is exactly the notions of a natural transformation. In fact, this notion evolved out of topological observations in which one wanted naturalities of morphisms between homology groups. In Atiyah-Macdonald you have probably seen a few instances from homological algebra and all these were inspired from topology.

Comment: More related to your example, the morphism $- \otimes_B B \to \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{Mod}_B}$ is not just an isomorphism in each component but indeed a natural transformation (which one checks immediately).

Comment: (I should probably have written an answer instead of three comments...)

Comment: Thank you!  So how would this work in my example; i.e. how does the fact that there are "no choices" for the isomorphism $A \otimes_A \otimes B \otimes_B C \cong A \otimes_A C$ imply that the diagram comutes without having to check such a thing manually?

Comment: You do have to check it but since there are no choices, it‘s straightforward to check. In fact, the thing one really checks here, is that there are indeed no choices. This is for sure something that one needs to get used to. (So once one gets used to it, one can often see within one glance that there is some naturality.)